# What is the meaning for the below code

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

The below code is for getting current row dropdown of gridview. but I am confused with this code. please explain me about this code. I got this code from one article.

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.Parent;
```

Comment: The parent of the parent of sender is parsed into a Dropdownlist is parsed into a Gridviewrow.
This is likely from within an eventhandler, which normally use the term sender.

Comment: Let's hope all casts turn out well and that there are no null references...

Answer (score 1):

That is a way to get the reference to the `GridViewRow` from a `DropDownList` from within it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event(for example). This works if the `DropDownList` is in a `TemplateField` of a `GridView`.

But the better way is using the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property.

For example:

```
protected void dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
}
```

It's better because it's less prone of errors. So the `GridViewRow` is still the `NamingContainer` even if you would put this dropdown into a `Panel` whereas the `Parent` approach would be incorrect then.

Answer (score 0):

It is for selecting the row, which contains the dropdown list. First it is converting the sender to Dropdownlist, then it is looking for Parent control, then that controls parent and converting that to a Gridview row.